# Merge two copies of the same git repository

Tags: git, github

I made a git repo `foo` and then started working. Twenty commits later, I copied over all the files from the repo into a new directory `bar` and created a new git repo. I now have twenty commits on the `bar` repo, too.

How do I merge the two repos so I have one clean history? I want to get rid of the first commit in the `bar` repo and append the rest to the `foo` repo.

Comment: `git-diff-tree` or `git-diff-files` with `-p` option will generate patch file. Apply it back at `foo` with `git apply` or `git am`

Comment: https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/

Answer (score 2):

You could add the second repository as a remote to the first repo and then rebase all those commits onto a branch of the `foo` repository.

Inside the `foo` repository do this to add the `bar` repository

```
$ git remote add bar <path-to-bar>
$ git fetch bar
```

Now find the commit you want to rebase (in your case the second one) and do

```
$ git rebase master <hash-of-second-commit>
```

Depending on how those two repositories differ everything could apply cleanly, or you might have to resolve merge conflicts.